# Compiler won't let me instantiate struct

Tags: solidity, remix

Usually this error shows up when declaring functions and goes away by adding "memory" next to the argument, but this time I can't get it to resolve. I'm trying to instantiate a struct that takes in two parameters:

```
struct Obj {
    string where;
    uint what;
    }


function do() public {
    obj=Obj("here",1);
    }
```

the line with the new Obj triggers: `TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.`

I tried putting "memory" all over the place, after the first argument, after the second, after both, after the function, etc. Nothing seems to appease the compiler.

I'm using `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works :

```
function foo() public {
Obj memory obj=Obj("here",1);
}
```

Solidity is a statically typed language so you have to specify the type of each variable.

For the difference between `storage`, `memory`, and `calldata`, you can check these two links :

- [What does the keyword "memory" do exactly?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/what-does-the-keyword-memory-do-exactly)
- [When should I use calldata and when should I use memory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74442/when-should-i-use-calldata-and-when-should-i-use-memory)