# default storage location

Tags: memory, calldata, stack

This post ([When should I use calldata and when should I use memory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/74442/when-should-i-use-calldata-and-when-should-i-use-memory)) explains the differences between calldata and memory. However where are function arguments or variables within functions stored if nothing is specified aka what is the default for each?

Examples:

```
function foo(string _exampleString) // where is the argument stored?

vs 

function foo(string memory _exampleString)
```

or

```
function foo(string _exampleString) public{
   uint256 memory bar = 1;
}

vs 

function foo(string _exampleString) public {
    uint256 bar = 1;   // where is the argument stored?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read on this [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.3.3/frequently-asked-questions.html) function arguments are always in memory. So both options will store the value on memory.

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. My question is why would you specify memory to a function argument if its the default place to be stored? why would you speciy calldata explicitly? Besides funciton arguments can also be stored in storage