# Calling a function with calldata parameter from another contract

Tags: solidity, memory, calldata

Contact A:

```
function redeemAssetsForBuyback(address[] calldata tokens) external {
  // ...
}
```

I would like to call `redeemAssetsForBuyback` from Contract B:

```
function initiateRedeem() external {
  // ...
  // I have address[] memory payload ready to be sent
  address[] memory myPayload;

  // Can I transform myPayload to address[] calldata?
  IContractA(contractAAdrress).redeemAssetsForBuyback(myPayload); // Parameter mismatchs
}
```

I can change the `redeemAssetsForBuyback` function's parameter to be memory instead of calldata and my issue resolves on JS VM at Remix but I read that I should be using calldata [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/74443/85505).

So, can I somehow create a `address[] calldata` on ContractB and call ContractA's function with it? If not, is it okay to use `redeemAssetsForBuyback(address[] memory tokens)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do so:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {
    event Received(bytes);
    
    function redeemAssetsForBuyback(address[] calldata) external{
      emit Received(msg.data);
    }      
}

contract B{
    function initiateRedeem(address _contractA, address[] calldata address_array) external {
        
        (bool success, ) = _contractA.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("redeemAssetsForBuyback(address[])", address_array)
        );
        
        require(success);
    }
}
```

If you deploy ContractA and pass the address of ContractA to `initiateRedeem()` in ContractB along with your array of address, it will make an call to `redeemAssetsForBuyback` function in contractA.